# Flash terminator tab on process exit or completion

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminator, bell

Any idea how to "flash" the `terminator` tabs on process completion? I was looking over `terminator_config` and set the `visible_bell = True` but it didn't seem to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The question sounds as if you want terminator to alert you when a command in one of the windows has completed.  Your shell would know this, but terminator doesn't really care: it runs the shell and the shell runs commands.

For instance, you could add the bell character to your prompt, making the terminal flash (or beep) each time you get a new prompt.

The [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html) tells how to embed control characters and escape sequences in your shell prompt.  For instance, the section on [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) shows that the bell character can be added using the `\a` escape.  Since `\a` is non-printing, you should enclose that in `\[` and `\]`, e.g., `\[\a\]`.